# Eliminating the Reason Field In Jira

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

In jira, there is required fields when creating issues, Reason being one of them. I would like to know if it's possible to eliminate it and replace it with another field that does the same thing. Anyone else ever done this before?

Comment: Could you provide some more information? I have never heard of a 'reason' field, so that suggests you are talking about a custom field. There are some mandatory fields when creating JIRA issues (ID, summary), but you can also configure other fields to be mandatory or even add your own mandatory custom fields. Perhaps a screenshot would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to make almost any field not required, to set up a project so that that field doesn't appear in the issues' screens, and to create a custom field, but I don't see the "Reason" field in our Jira Cloud field list, so it may be a custom field already.

I'll warn you that proliferating custom fields makes administering the system more complex, so think about whether you can fit your process to the existing field. It's not clear from your question what exactly you want your new field to do differently from "Reason".

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was told from my co-workers who worked more in Jira that Jira requires it, and because Jira requires it, that it can't be eliminated. She gave me the task of trying to replace it with another field, and thinks that the reason field and resolution field are similar in functionality so she wants to eliminate one being the reason field.

Comment: I am not so sure that "Reason" can't be gotten rid of. You should be able to edit the screens in your configuration to exclude it and, if it is set as a "required" field, make it optional. If you have been using it the past, I suggest not deleting it completely, in order not to lose historical information.

Comment: You were right. Sorry, I got the wrong information from someone. I appreciate all the help. I figured out how to eliminate the reason field, and I was asked to eliminate it completely due to being on a project. If they want it back, the team I was on who originally asked me in the first place can put it back. They're the ones playing around with it, testing what they want for fields. I got pulled on another project, so it's their problem now :)

Comment: Sounds like someone else should be asking questions rather than making hasty assumptions. Glad to hear you're free of the headache, anyway!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, now this person has to answer to me....bwahhahhahaaha ::evil grin::